# How to align text under a flex image?

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to display some text below the two pictures.

Below the closing divs to be exact. The text is incorrectly displayed on the side of the image.

What am I doing wrong?

It's my first time posting here in a long time so I apologize for any posting mistakes.

```css
/* Helper classes */

.container {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}

.my-sec-1-mt {
  margin-top: 4rem;
}

.my-sec-2-mt {
  margin-top: 1.8rem;
}


/* Services section */

.rmi-services_services-wrapper display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
gap: 1.8rem;
.rmi-services__service-gallery {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 0.8rem;
}

.rmi-services__service-gallery>.rmi-services__service-visual {
  display: flex;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.rmi-services__service-gallery>.rmi-services__service-visual picture {
  height: 100%;
}

.rmi-services__service-gallery>.rmi-services__service-visual img {
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<section class="rmi-services my-sec-1-mt">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="rmi-services__services-wrapper my-sec-2-mt">
      <div class="rmi-services__service">
        <div class="rmi-services__service-gallery">
          <div class="rmi-services__service-visual curve-border">
            <picture>
              <source srcset="{% static 'image_location" type="image/webp">
              <img loading="lazy" class="img-left" src="{% static 'image_location' %}" alt="">
            </picture>
          </div>

          <div class="rmi-services__service-visual curve-border">
            <picture>
              <source srcset="{% static 'image_location" type="image/webp">
              <img loading="lazy" src="{% static 'image_location' %}" alt="">
            </picture>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: The code you posted doesn't reproduce the problem you're describing. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: It would be somewhat difficult to reproduce what I have. But I will try to do so in a bit.